# Proximity sensor stop working after one minute

Tags: android

I am building a app in which using proximity sensor i detect the object is near of far from the screen and when as per that i am doing screen on or off.
Proximity sensor works perfectly but after one minute proximity sensor stops working and i am not able to detect object is near or far from the mobile screen.
And when after register proximity sensor, i open google map which is also a part of my application, proximity sensor stops working immediately.I am really not able to understand why this is happening.

```
public class ScreenOnOff extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn_on,btn_off;
    SensorManager mySensorManager;
    Sensor myProximitySensor;
    private PowerManager powerManager;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    private int field = 0x00000020;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_on_off);

        btn_on = findViewById(R.id.sensor_on);
        btn_off = findViewById(R.id.sensor_off);


        mySensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        myProximitySensor = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(
                Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);

        try {
            // Yeah, this is hidden field.
            field = PowerManager.class.getClass().getField("PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK").getInt(null);
        } catch (Throwable ignored) {
        }

        powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(field, getLocalClassName());

        btn_on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (myProximitySensor == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(ScreenOnOff.this, "sensor not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                        mySensorManager.registerListener(proximitySensorEventListener, myProximitySensor,
                                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(ScreenOnOff.this, "Enable autolock mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

        btn_off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mySensorManager.unregisterListener(proximitySensorEventListener, myProximitySensor);
                Toast.makeText(ScreenOnOff.this, "Disable autolock mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    SensorEventListener proximitySensorEventListener
            = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {

                if (event.values[0] == 0) {
                    if(!wakeLock.isHeld()) {
                        wakeLock.acquire();
                        Log.d("screenvalue:", String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
                    }
                } else {
                    if(wakeLock.isHeld()){
                        wakeLock.release();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Have you found the solution? I am also facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
public class ScreenOnOff extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_on_off);

        ....

        btn_on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (myProximitySensor == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(ScreenOnOff.this, "sensor not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                        mySensorManager.registerListener(ScreenOnOff.this, myProximitySensor,
                            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(ScreenOnOff.this, "Enable autolock mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        btn_off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mySensorManager.unregisterListener(ScreenOnOff.this, myProximitySensor);
                Toast.makeText(ScreenOnOff.this, "Disable autolock mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {

            if (event.values[0] == 0) {
                if(!wakeLock.isHeld()) {
                    wakeLock.acquire();
                    Log.d("screenvalue:", String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
                }
            } else {
                if(wakeLock.isHeld()){
                    wakeLock.release();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that it's a better approach to register your listener in `onResume` and unregister it in `onPause` event of your activity. (Control registration using a proper boolean)

Comment: But i have to keep running sensor if it's in background also. And i tried to register listener in onResume but still it's stops working after one minute.For running it again i have to open application to register listener.

Comment: In order for the proximity sensor to deliver results to your application, your app need to remain open while it is in background (not getting killed by system to use the memory), so you should keep your app alive using a foreground service.

Comment: yes my app is active in background but still i am getting this problem